# Local variable initialized in a condition not recognized?

Tags: c++, global-variables, local-variables

I am learning c++ and I came across a really odd phenomenon in a program. I haven't seen any documentation on this problem. Why is that when I initialize a variable inside of a conditional statement it isn't recognized outside of it? Is the variable local to the conditional statement?

Here is an example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*scope / range of variables */


int global;

int main()
{
   int local = rand();

   cout << "value of global " << global << endl;
   cout << "value of local " << local << endl;

   int test = 10;

   if (test == 0)
   {
      int result = test * 10;
   }

   cout << "result :" << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case result is undefined. Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Read up about "scope" in your C++ textbook.

Comment: Variable `result` is local to `if` statement scope. It does not exist outside that scope.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your declaration of `result` is local inside the `if()` blocks *scope* you provided:

```
if (test == 0)
{ // Defines visibility of any declarations made inside
  int result = test * 10;
} //  ^^^^^^
```

Hence the statement

```
cout << "result :" << result << endl;
```

would lead to a compiler error, since `result` isn't visible for the compiler at this point outside that *scope*.

---

But even if you declare `result` correctly outside of the scope block, your logic

```
int result = 0; // Presumed for correctness
int test = 10;

if (test == 0)
{
    result = test * 10; // Note the removed declaration
}
```

doesn't make much sense, since `test` was given the value `10` immediately before testing it against the value `0` in your your `if()` statements condition, and the condition never would become true.